# Curl Works on Server A but Times Out on Server B

Tags: curl, timeout

I'm trying to do a CURL that I can get working on my machine, which I'll call Machine A.

However, I get a timeout when I run the same command using a different machine, Machine B.

I can't for the life of me figure out why it works on one vs. the other.  Both Machines are actually on Amazon EC2, with the same Security Groups, Subnets, etc.  Both Machine A and Machine B are running Ubuntu 12.04, both are running CURL 7.22.  Both have no iptable firewalls set.  Both machines are able to curl most websites just fine (ie. curl yahoo.com works)

Here's what happens on **Machine A**:

```
curl -v -k https://api.blabla.org
* About to connect() to api.blabla.org port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 198.22.157.57...
* Connected to api.blabla.org (192.200.63.41) port 443 (#0)
```

Here's what happens on **Machine B**:

```
curl -v -k https://api.blabla.org
* About to connect() to api.blabla.org port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 198.22.157.57...  Connection timed out
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Anyone have any idea what settings on Machine B could be different that might cause it to fail for this CURL?

Answer (score 0):

I think my IP address is being actively blocked.

Comment: Is the output of `traceroute` same on both machines?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem here, still can't figure out why.
I did a work around :
I did a simple php file on server B where it's working, to run the curl and just send back the response.
and I call server B from server A instead of making the curl directly from server A.

I know it's dirty but works ...